# no method matching write(::IOStream, ::MyClass)

Tags: julia

I am using a julia v0.6 code. But my julia version is v1.1. I don't know how to modify this piece of code

```
roadway_HOLO = open(io->read_dxf(io, Roadway, dist_threshold_lane_connect=2.0), joinpath(@__DIR__, "../data/ngsim_HOLO.dxf"), "r")

convert_curves_feet_to_meters!(roadway_HOLO)

open(io->write(io, roadway_HOLO), joinpath(@__DIR__, "../data/ngsim_HOLO.txt"), "w")
```

The error occurs at the last line of the code. Please help.

```
ERROR: LoadError: LoadError: MethodError: no method matching write(::IOStream, ::AutomotiveDrivingModels.Roadway)
Closest candidates are:
  write(::IO, ::Any) at io.jl:498
  write(::IO, ::Any, ::Any...) at io.jl:500
  write(::IOStream, ::UInt8) at iostream.jl:378
  ...
Stacktrace:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are using this [AutomotiveDrivingModels.jl](https://github.com/sisl/AutomotiveDrivingModels.jl). It [seems to be that](https://github.com/sisl/AutomotiveDrivingModels.jl/blob/70a2be738d73fb25ed8756ee299312d46e3b9695/src/roadways/roadways.jl#L241) you need to pass `MIME("text/plain")` to the call to `write` in order to write your `Roadway` object to a text file.

```
open(io->write(io, MIME("text/plain"), roadway_HOLO), joinpath(@__DIR__, "../data/ngsim_HOLO.txt"), "w")
# or
open(io->write(io, MIME"text/plain"(), roadway_HOLO), joinpath(@__DIR__, "../data/ngsim_HOLO.txt"), "w")
```

Note that you can also use `do` syntax with methods whose first argument is a `Function` like `open`. The call above is equivalent to the following call below.

```
open(joinpath(@__DIR__, "../data/ngsim_HOLO.txt"), "w") do io
    write(io, MIME("text/plain"), roadway_HOLO)
end
```

As a side note, `methods(write)` should normally show the `write` method(s) for `Roadway` type and also `?write` should show the docstring for this `write` method. If you happen to see a similar error in the future, you might want to try these to find the correct method signature.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Serialization` to store Julia objects in a file:

Consider some custom data structure and some object.

```
struct Some
    x::String
    y::Int
end

s = Some("test 123",12345)
```

The above structure can be serialized with the following command:

```
using Serialization
open("file.bin","w") do f
    serialize(f,s)
end
```

Now let us test deserialization:

```
julia>  open("file.bin") do f; println(deserialize(f)==s); end
true
```